# Unit Testing - 'fixtures' no method error using No-Brainer ORM

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-5, rethinkdb, nobrainer

I am trying to write unit tests for my database using fixtures in rails 5.0.1.

I keep getting the error:

```html
test/test_helper.rb:7:in `<class:TestCase>': undefined method `fixtures' for ActiveSupport::TestCase:Class (NoMethodError)
 from /Users/Stephan/ruby/react/test/test_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
 from /Users/Stephan/ruby/react/test/models/blog_test.rb:1:in `require'
 from /Users/Stephan/ruby/react/test/models/blog_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 from /Users/Stephan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:11:in `require'
 from /Users/Stephan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:11:in `block in require_files'
 from /Users/Stephan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:10:in `each'
 from /Users/Stephan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:10:in `require_files'
 from /Users/Stephan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:86:in `plugin_rails_init'
 from /Users/Stephan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/minitest-5.10.1/lib/minitest.rb:80:in `block in init_plugins'
 from /Users/Stephan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/minitest-5.10.1/lib/minitest.rb:78:in `each'
 from /Users/Stephan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/minitest-5.10.1/lib/minitest.rb:78:in `init_plugins'
 from /Users/Stephan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/minitest-5.10.1/lib/minitest.rb:129:in `run'
 from /Users/Stephan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:73:in `run'
 from /Users/Stephan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/minitest-5.10.1/lib/minitest.rb:62:in `block in autorun'
```

Everything in the test_helper.rb is out of the box ruby 2.4.0 and rails 5.0.1.

```html
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'


class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. For reference here is the test_helper.rb file